# A UIScrollview that auto scroll and Stop at every Pages for atleast 2seconds

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am using **NSTimer** to move through my **UIScrollview**, but I can't get to make it stop at every page for like let's say a second or two so users can be able to preview and click if they want to or when they are scrolling around the **images** in the **UIScrollview** my **Code** is below....:

```
    -(void) onTimer {

CGPoint rightOffset = CGPointMake(responseScroll.contentSize.width - responseScroll.bounds.size.width, 0);
[responseScroll setContentOffset:rightOffset animated:YES];
}


 -(void)viewDidLoad {

 /-------/
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.008 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer)   userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the timer interval 2.0:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This means that the timer will fire every 2 seconds.

If you want to shift one page over, you need to adjust your onTimer method:

```
CGPoint rightOffset = CGPointMake(responseScroll.contentOffset.x + responseScroll.frame.size.width, 0);
[responseScroll setContentOffset:rightOffset animated:YES];
```

Comment: 2.0 makes it scroll straight to the last page, no wait interval

Answer (score 0):

Consider using UIAnimations instead

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [self moveScrollView];
}

-(void)moveScrollView{
    CGPoint rightOffset = CGPointMake(responseScroll.contentOffset.x+responseScroll.bounds.size.width, 0);
    if(rightOffset.x+responseScroll.bounds.size.width<=responseScroll.contentSize.width){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
           [responseScroll setContentOffset:rightOffset animated:NO];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self moveScrollView];
            });
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: The view scroll straight to the last view, but if i scroll to the view before the last, it stays for a second before going to the las. But, if it's the view two screens before the last, it'll skip straight to the last

Comment: I've updated my answer and the rightOffset property, can you confirm you have this behavior with this update?

Comment: Lol, it's cool but it now move to infinity after getting to the last view

Comment: Error on this line '(rightOffset+responseScroll.bounds.size.width<=responseScroll.contentSize.width)'

Comment: Stopped scrolling, can we move it to chat?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, this is in swift. This will scroll the pages in scrollview infinitely.

```
private func startBannerSlideShow()
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 6, delay: 0.1, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
        scrollviewOutlt.contentOffset.x = (scrollviewOutlt.contentOffset.x == scrollviewOutlt.bounds.width*2) ? 0 : scrollviewOutlt.contentOffset.x+scrollviewOutlt.bounds.width
    }, completion: { (status) in
        self.startBannerSlideShow()
    })
}
```